# Loading multiple data objects from backend API - all at once or every data object in its own call?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Lets say i have a form that i use to edit a Customer. In addition to various input fields it will also have multiple drop down lists to set some fields (eg. Country, Category, Status...). Every drop down list will need a seperate lists that i need to get from the backend to populate.
That means that if i want to edit a customer with my form, i need to load:

- The Customer Object which will be edited
- A list of countries
- A list of categories
- A list of different stattus types
- ...

My question is:
Should each of these things be loaded seperatly with its own backend API call, or should i write a API backend call that will combine all these things into a single object and use it to load my data?

Comment: Honestly, it depends on the scenario - for the drop downs; are there other parts of the system that would use the same data? Personally, I'd design the API around reusability - if a particular endpoint serves multiple parts of the system, then altering it later becomes easier. But at the same time, if the system isn't going to change in future, loading all the data in one hit tends to be better for the user.

Comment: Yes, the APIs that would load the lists are supposed to be reusable in many places

Comment: I use Spring Boot as my backend using the Controller/Service/Repository pattern. I guess i could make in my controller layer a endpoint that will construct a comprehensive data object, and at the same time have endpoints fur seperate data objects and aall of thhem will use the same service method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's better use multiple API call in almost situation.
After compare pros and cons as table below, I always choose Multiple API call for projects.

Credit to Andrew Corrigan and Amrit remind me some criterias.

|  | Single API | Multiple API |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Network | Less request | Multiple request => Caching |
| UI Render | Render data in nearly same time | Render if any api response |
| Reuse FE component | Need to call big API to take one array data | Get what needed |
| Reusability API | Low | High |
| Single Responsibility | No | Yes |
| Flexible | No | Yes |

Comment: Good point, but for "Reuse FE component" i want to say that if i controll the backend, i can just custom make different API end-point for different use-cases. Meaning i can make 1 end-point that loads only a Customer object, and another one which will loads a Customer object together with a list of tasks for that customer. But that would potentialy mean a huge number of end-point. Not sure if that is a good Idea.

Comment: Your problem now is architect of the application. I don't suggest that implement because  the application increase complexity rapidly. So now you shoud care about the responsibilty of each use-case and the flexibility of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Its an opinion based and scenario based , but in my suggestion i would prefer
things be loaded separately with its own backend API because :

```
1.Single api will be heavy and UX will be badly impacted

2.User may  not change all field when form opens so only changing fields will be using api
```